# How @RequestBody can handle encrypted jSON structure in request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a requirement, a JSON will be encrypted and added in request body from rest client.
At server Side, I have a REST API with this method.

`createOrder(@RequestBody(required = true) final OrderDTO item), @RequestParam(required = false) final String flag)
{.....}`

The architecture is using Spring.

Now What can be done to decrypt the incoming JSON so that `@RequestBody` can assign it properly into OrderDTO.

plz help in detail as early as possible.

**1) if Filter can be used or some other mechanism ?**

**2) The method createOrder() only the @RequestBody parameter will be encrypted. rest of the parameters will be sent from client as plaintext.**

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think one of the best way to secure rest WS is to use OAout2 using token that will be added in http head for each request

Answer (score 1):

You need to intercept the incoming `HttpServletRequest`.
The only way you can do that is by registering a `Filter`, and wrapping the actual `HttpServletRequest` with a custom implementation of `HttpServletRequestWrapper`.

You can override the `getReader()` method and provide your `BufferedReader`.
The `BufferedReader` could be constructed using a `StringReader` containing the decrypted request body (you need to entirely read the original `BufferedReader` first).

@Rich approach is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom `HttpMessageConverter`. The HttpMessageConverter API is responsible for converting beans to & from HTTP entities (query parameters, request body etc.)

You will need to write a Converter which decrypts the JSON and passes it to Jackson or similar.

See

- [Spring docs, 1.11.7. Message Converters](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-message-converters)
- [A tutorial on how to Configure HttpMessageConverter in Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) (www.baeldung.com)

(You could also accept the request body as a String and decrypt and deserialize it in the controller method body. That might be "ugly", but will probably be simpler and quicker.)